# symfony 4 route trouble after install

Tags: symfony, routes

So I just installed clean Symfony 4.

My simple controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ArticleController{

    public function index(){

        return new Response('Hello');
    }
}
```

and routes.yaml

```
index:
path: /
controller: App\Controller\ArticleController::index
```

in public/index.php it says:
No route found for ".../public/index.php"

and also I was trying to set up my domain for localhost on windows, with file in apache and in system32, on http://mypath it opets https and says there is security problem

Comment: Install the [Symfony server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html) Verify things are working as expected then go back and trouble shoot your [Apache configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

coud you look at the output of this commad and see if your router in the list

```
                  php bin/console debug:router
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Use comments for requesting additional information.

Comment: And getting down voted is not going to help.  Be patient.  Generate a few solid answers and you will be there.  Consider making a fresh S4 install and then trying to reproduce the error message.  If nothing else you will probably realize that it's a server configuration issue.